# User identity claims where the combination of two identifiers is unique

Tags: identityserver4, claims-based-identity

We are using IdentityServer4 for managing user identities and logins. In the business domain there are companies that are divided into organizations. Companies are distinguished by unique identifiers, while organization identifiers might clash between different companies, which makes only the combination of company ID and organization ID unique.

A normal user typically has access only to some organizations in one company, but there is a need for superusers that have access to organizations in multiple companies. The claims in IdentityServer were originally designed only for one company, so it has not really been thought how multiple companies should fit into this.

For a normal user it would totally fine that he would have one company claim and one or many organization claims. But this does not really work for superusers that need to access many organizations in many companies.

How should this kind of combination identifier be modelled? The only way we can come up with is combining the company ID and organization ID into one claim, but that means that we must split the claim everywhere we need to have the identifiers separated, which feels rather cumbersome and error prone. So is there a better or more proper way, or is this perhaps a problem that should be fixed outside of Identity server?

Comment: Apparently, IdentityServer4 supports JSON claim types, which sounds awesome and would solve our problem.

Comment: your intention to use json objects is absolutely correct. that is not something Identityserver specific, see the [spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Claims)